# Particle と in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 軽口**と**お喋りが過ぎて伯母さんには嫌われてたっけ。

What is the meaning of と？They were describing someone. The only thing I could guess would be "When", but I'm not sure since the phrase would be kind of strange.

EDIT : I'm sorry, as murakamifund300 stated, the real problem wasn't the meaning of と - which just means "and" - but the two nouns before and after were - which are not identical as I thought at first.

Comment: と can mean *when* only when it follows a noun.

Comment: Oh, really ? Wait, are you sure about that ? I think I've read a lot of times と used after a verb.

Comment: For exemple : "いつも上機嫌な真里亞お姉ちゃんを見ていると、こっちまで心が温かくなってくる。" と is used after 見ている, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wanted to say と can mean *when* when it follows a *verb*.

Comment: Ah, I see. No problem. You taught me something either way, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning is of the particle in this situation simply translates to "and".

Comment: Hm, wouldn't that be strange as well ? He is talkative and talks too much ? Doesn't it mean the same thing ?

Comment: He is talkative(1) "as well as" talkative(2) which made his aunt dislike him. The first talkative "軽口" is most commonly used as something like... talkative as in "having a loose tongue", or "not being able to keep secrets". The second talkative "お喋りが過ぎて" translates to "because of being too talkative", I guess at the magnitude of making his aunt very annoyed. So yea both similar meanings put together with a particle "と"。I don't know the context, but this 伯母さん doesn't necessary have to be his "aunt" as we call our friend's moms that way as well. Or he may have been working at somewhere before.

Comment: I see ! Well, it seems the problem wasn't the と particle ! Thank you !